# Locus of point imaginary numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the equation $z= a+2bt + ct^2$ represents a parabola in general,and a straight line if $\dfrac bc$ is real. 
How should I approach the problem i.e whose locus is to be determined $t$ or $z$?

Comment: What are $a,b,c,t,z$? Real numbers, complex numbers, integers? Are they constant? Are they known?

Comment: So $t$ is a real parameter (time?) and the coefficients $a,b,c$ are complex constants? Then it could be the locus of all $z$ as $t$ "runs" between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would demonstrate that the equation $z= a+2bt + ct^2$ represents a parabola in general, and a straight line if $b/c$ is real. First I must transform the equation to a canonical form that is unarguably a parabola. To that end, I look at *one* canonical form of the parabola, namely,

$$w=\frac{p}{2}(u+i)^2$$

This suggests to me that $p=2|c|$ and that I should rotate $z$ by $e^{-i\alpha}$ where $\alpha=\arg c$. Indeed $z\mapsto ze^{-i\alpha}$ rotates the function $z$ such that its axis is parallel to to the $x$-axis. We complete the operation by moving the *nose* of the parabola to the origin by subtracting $ae^{-i\alpha}$. Thus we have our transformed function

$$
\begin{align}
Z=(z-a)e^{-i\alpha}
&=be^{-i\alpha}t+ce^{-i\alpha}t^2\\
&=ce^{-i\alpha}t\left(\frac{b}{c}+t \right)\\
&=(A+Bt)^2-A^2
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
B=\sqrt{ce^{-i\alpha}}\\
A=\frac{be^{-i\alpha}}{2B}
$$

Thus, I have shown through simple transformations (rotation and translation) that the original $z$ can be expressed in the canonical form of the parabola.

Now to the second part of the question; demonstrate that $z$ (or $Z$) is a straight line when $b/c$ is real. Let's begin with

$$
Z=ce^{-i\alpha}t\left(\frac{b}{c}+t \right)
$$

Assuming that $b/c$ is real, let's express this in polar form, i.e., $Z=re^{i\theta}$,

$$
r=|Z|=|ce^{-i\alpha}|t\left(\frac{b}{c}+t \right)\\
\begin{align}
\theta
&=\tan^{-1}\frac{\Im\{Z\}}{\Re\{Z\}}\\
&=\tan^{-1}\frac{\Im\{ce^{-i\alpha}\}t\left(\frac{b}{c}+t \right)}{\Re\{ce^{-i\alpha}\}t\left(\frac{b}{c}+t \right)}\\
&=\tan^{-1}\frac{\Im\{ce^{-i\alpha}\}}{\Re\{ce^{-i\alpha}\}}\\
&=\arg ce^{-i\alpha}\\
&=\mathbf{constant}
\end{align}\\
$$

Since $\theta$ is a constant, that proves that $Z$, and hence $z$, is a straight line.